# npm environment or shell to run dependent modules locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Does `npm` has a shell or environment inbuilt, which can be used to run `node` `modules` installed locally ?

Ex:

I have `nodeunit`, `eslint` and other packages listed in my `dependencies`. I can run commands provided by these dependencies from `npm scripts` like:

```
"lint": "eslint .",
"test": "nodeunit test/*js",
```

These commands cannot be run outside `npm scripts`. I know, with a small configuration we can achieve this (by updating the `PATH` with `node_modules/.bin`), but I am wondering if there is `npm` way of doing this (something like `npm shell` which would enable this).

In other words:

In my project dir I will not be able to run this: `nodeunit .` because `nodeunit` is not available in the `PATH`. When I execute `npm test`, `npm` adds `node_modules/.bin` to `PATH`, hence `nodeunit` is available under `npm test` script. My question is: Is there a `npm` way which will enables us to execute these commands in the project directory without using them in `npm scripts`

Comment: You mean like: `node` -> `console.log("hi, console");` Alternatively, `node myfile.js`

Comment: Yeah but not for `node`, for `npm`. Ideally I should be able to run like `nodeunit .` after enabling the shell or environment.

Comment: ....NPM just utilizes node to run javascript in a file.

Comment: In my project dir I will not be able to run this `nodeunit .` because nodeunit is not available in the `PATH`. When I execute `npm test`, `npm` adds `node_modules/.bin` to `PATH` hence nodeunit is available under `npm test` script. My question is: Is there a npm way which will enables us to execute these commands in the project directory without using `npm scripts` ?

Comment: You need to install nodeunit globally then

Comment: I don't want to install globally. If I have version specific dependent modules, I can't install them globally since they can conflict for other projects. (Also, `nodeunit` is just an example)

Comment: Short of running a batch file to open a command prompt with the `PATH` already set properly, I don't think this is possible.